# FinalBuilder alternative for Mac OS X?

Tags: iphone, xcode, build-process, macos

I use finalbuilder (http://www.finalbuilder.com/) for my build process.

I wonder if exist a alternative to run in OSX. I could try to run finalbuilder inside a Windows virtual machine and run from SSH commands from there but still I want sometime to automatize the build process of my iPhone apps.

I don't find a tool like FB with graphical input and a decent set of build actions.

If a graphical tool not exist, then the most friendly option which are? Maybe something in python or ruby?

Comment: Running ssh commands using cygwin and RSA keys works okay in a mixed environment.

Answer (score 0):

SCons is written in Python, been around for a while and pretty powerful:  http://www.scons.org/

Answer (score 0):

How much of the process are you looking at controlling from the tool vs from Xcode?

If you're going to define the build process in Xcode and you're just looking at something to invoke the Xcode command-line build you could use CruiseControl and its [xcodebuilder](http://blog.jeffreyfredrick.com/2008/11/27/continuous-integration-for-iphonexcode-projects/).

This isn't at all equivalent to FinalBuilder but I did use this successfully to do CI on [this iPhone app](http://iphone.wavewatch.com/).

Answer (score 0):

[Buildbot](http://buildbot.net/trac/wiki/Documentation) looks like it can handle most things - its open source, cross platform and Google seem to like it for [chromium.org](http://build.chromium.org/buildbot/waterfall/console)

I haven't used it - it looks very geared towards the high end.

I have however had extensive experience with Scons and CruiseControl. I wouldn't recommend anyone use either of these systems - the amount of scripting required to actual work done ratio is incredibly high.